# No data is showing up in my UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

My `IBOutlet` for songName is set up correctly, but for some reason

```
import UIKit

class QueueController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let testUser = Profile.init(username: "test", followers: [], following: [])
        let songOne = Song.init(name: "S1", UWR: testUser.username, genre: "rock", artist: "s1")
        var moreSongs = [Song]()
        moreSongs = [Song(name: "gah", UWR: testUser.username, genre: "gahh", artist: "GAH")]
        Queue.createQueue("2321x", creator: testUser, firstSong: songOne, additionalSongs: moreSongs)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Queue.theQueue!.count
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if let feed = Queue.theQueue {
            return feed.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    func songIndex(cellIndex: Int) -> Int {
        return tableView.numberOfSections - cellIndex - 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let song = Queue.theQueue![songIndex(indexPath.section)]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("queueCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QueueCell
        //cell.textLabel?.text = song.name this doesnt work also
        cell.songName.text = "asdad"

        return cell
    }

}
```

For my `Queue` class:

```
import UIKit

class Queue {
    let creator:Profile!
    let planetID:String!
    let beginningSong: Song!
    var feed:Array<Song>?
    static var theQueue:Array<Song>?

    init (id:String!, creator:Profile!, firstSong:Song!) {
        self.planetID = id
        self.creator = creator
        self.beginningSong = firstSong
    }

    func addSong (song: Song) {
        feed?.append(song)
    }

    static func createQueue (id:String!, creator:Profile!, firstSong:Song!, additionalSongs: [Song]) {
        let temp = Queue(id: id, creator: creator, firstSong: firstSong)

        for song in additionalSongs {
            temp.addSong(song)
        }

        self.theQueue = temp.feed
    }
}
```

`Song` class:

```
import UIKit

class Song {
    let name:String!
    let userWhoRequested:String!
    let genre: String?
    let artist: String?

    init (name:String!, UWR:String!, genre:String?, artist:String?) {
        self.name = name
        self.userWhoRequested = UWR
        self.genre = genre
        self.artist = artist
    }
}


class QueueCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var songName:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPicture:UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var isCurrent:UIImageView!
}
```

The table view displays properly but no data shows up in my controller, and I'm not sure why. The reuse cell identifier is also correct. The data in `viewDidLoad()` is also in my app delegate's `func application`.

Thanks!

Comment: did u set the datasource and delegate for the table view ? Also did u check the data is not nil in numberOfRows method ?

Comment: How do i set the datasource and delegate? I followed a tutorial for a basic set up but they didn't cover that and googling hasn't helped. By default it says they're the "Root View Controller" because I had made my view controller a navigation controller. How do I check if the data is not nil?

Comment: you dont have to set data source, for a UITableViewController, dataSource and delegate are preset

Comment: @AkshanshThakur oh okay. What should I do then?

Comment: @user5812721 I'm debugging your code. I'll respond in a bit

Comment: Put breakpoints in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView`. What values are being returned by each one?

Comment: Where is `feed` in `Queue` initialized? And why for heaven's sake is it (and also `theQueue`) optional? Is the *physical* table view optional, too?

Comment: One problem is with your noofsections. It is 0. why? because your feed is nil

Comment: @nebs numberOfSectionsInTableView returned 0, and I'm not sure how to find what numberOfRowsInSection returned since I didn't override it.

Comment: `feed` is initialized in `viewDidLoad` -> `Queue.createQueue`. I'm not sure why I made them optional, I was following a tutorial. And no I don't believe the physical table view is optional.

Comment: @AkshanshThakur I thought my `viewDidLoad` -> `Queue.createQueue` would fill it, why did it not?

Comment: @user5812721 that's why your tableview is empty, you need at least 1 section.  You did override `numberOfRowsInSection`, you are returning `Queue.theQueue!.count` in there.  Check that count to make sure it's greater than 0 too.

Comment: I don't see that `feed` is initialized in `viewDidLoad`. Declare `feed` and `theQueue` as non optional and the compiler will help you. And when you set `numberOfSectionsInTableView` to 1 the app will crash with that optionals.

Comment: the queue you are creating in `createQueue` is going to be freed immediately upon `createQueue` returning because no one holds a strong pointer to it.

Comment: self.theQueue = temp.feed
This is what you did, infact, the feed was never initialized in createqueue, you. But you also, made self.theQueue nil

Comment: @vacawama So how do I not make it free immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the feed inside your CreateQueue method, that was never initialized

And change

```
var feed:Array<Song>?
```

to

```
var feed  = [Song]()
```

Comment: Okay, so I added `self.feed!.append(firstSong)` but it came up with an error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: I have a feeling you also have problem with your cell identifier. Please go to your storyboard and on your table View Controller, select your cell. Then go to the identity inspector of your CELL.  and type in the identifier that you have mentioned queueCell, in your case

Comment: It works! Thanks! I'm confused as to how `var feed:Array<Song>` is different than `var feed = [Song]()`

Comment: var feed: Array<Song> is just creating a variable named feed and setting it to nil. var feed = [Song]() is initializing it to an array of 0 elements. So, it is possible to add something to an array with 0 elements, but not possible to add something to nil.. nil? haha

Comment: Right! Thank you so much. Also the list that displays on my phone is `gah` `gah` `S1` `S1`, yet I only add 2 songs to the queue

Comment: I think that is because you append to the feed twice, once with the function addSong.

Comment: try getting rid of that function @user5812721, maybe it will work

Comment: I got rid of it and replaced `temp.addSong(song)` with `temp.feed.append(song)` in the for loop in `createQueue` and it still does the same thing.

Comment: how many rows do you get when you add breakpoint at numberOfRowsInSection ? And how many sections now?

Comment: If I haven't overrided that function, how do I do a breakpoint on it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113352/discussion-between-akshansh-thakur-and-user5812721).